# How do I return a Null value when an element is missing from Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script where I get some data from a web page in Selenium using Python. However for some of the pages I'm scraping through, some of the elements are not present and this throws a `NoSuchElementException` error.
How do I return a null value for when the element is not present. I reied using `or None` but it still throws the error. Also, the elements following this one also depend on the presence of the first one as shown below:

```
metadata = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Complete metadata on ') or None
metadata_url = metadata.get_attribute('href') or None
dataset_id = metadata_url.split('metadata/')[1] or None

output_dict['datasets'].append({'title': dataset_title, 'url': dataset_link, 'metadata_url': metadata_url})
```

The element that is missing from some pages is the `metadata`.
I'm looking to populate the `metadata_url` field as `null`.
Please assist with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```py
var = function_call(param) or None
```

runs the function, gets the output, transforms this output into a boolean (see [truthyness in python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/)), and if that output is `False`, then it sets that variable to `None` instead.
However, the function (`find_element`, here) doesn't return a Falsy value, but raises a `NoSuchElementException` exception if it doesn't find anything.
That means you need to use a `try except` block in your code instead of the `or None`

```py
try:
    metadata = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Complete metadata on ')
    # If we are at this line, then find_element found something, and we
    # can set values for our url and dataset id
    metadata_url = metadata.get_attribute('href')  # this will be None if there's no href attribute
    dataset_id = metadata_url.split('metadata/')[1]
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    metadata_url = None
    dataset_id = None
```

In the case when `metadata_url` is `None`, you will need to handle that case, because `metadata_url.split` will not work, it will raise a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Comment: When I run it, I get a NameError: name 'selenium' is not defined. Was I supposed to import selenium from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, add the import at the start of the code! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to use JS syntax in Python. You'll have to instead check if the element exists first.

```
if not metadata_url:
  return None
```